# Gui Displaying a Text Doc - How to split lines up

Tags: java, user-interface

So I want my file reader to display the contents of a text file which I have been working, but it displays it all in one big line, I've tried the line splitter etc. but it does not work.

```
JTabbedPane jtp1=new JTabbedPane();
JTabbedPane jtp2=new JTabbedPane();
JPanel jp1=new JPanel();
JTextArea t1=new JTextArea();
MainGui() throws Exception
{
    super("" + Settings.Name + " By Brandon");
    FileReader f=new FileReader("");
    BufferedReader brk=new BufferedReader(f);      
    String line;
    while((line=brk.readLine())!=null){
        t1.append(line);
    }
    //jp1.add(t1);
    jtp1.addTab("Reports",t1);
    getContentPane().add(jtp1);       
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    MainGui mv1=new MainGui();
    mv1.pack();
    mv1.setVisible(true);   
    mv1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
}
```

Inside the text document there is around 30 lines of data like shown below each only takes one line.

How would I make the GUI display it like the text document?

> [21-Dec-2013 17:43:24 Greenwich Mean Time] Brandon has reported: Report for: Seriously offensive language

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Get the source to read itself.  Also look at 1) [`JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29).  2) [`JTextArea.setLineWrap(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap%28boolean%29) 3) [`JTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setWrapStyleWord%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
t1.append(line + "\n"); //add line break to each append
```